# Proper design to avoid Oracle deadlocks?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, deadlock

The usual advice when it comes to avoiding deadlocks is to always lock resources in the same order. But how would you implement this with regards to row locks in highly contented Oracle database?

To see what I mean, consider the following example. A very simple DAO to handle bank accounts:

```
@Component
public class AccountDao {

    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void withdraw(String account, int amount) {
        modifyBalance(account, -amount);
    }

    public void deposit(String account, int amount) {
        modifyBalance(account, amount);
    }

    private void modifyBalance(String account, int amount) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
            PreparedStatement statement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("update account set balance = balance + ? where holder = ?");
            statement.setInt(1, amount);
            statement.setString(2, account);
            statement.execute();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To execute a transfer between two accounts, there is some sort of `InternalBankTransfer` class that has a transfer method:

```
    public void transfer(String from, String to, int amount) {
        // start transaction
        accountDao.withDraw(from, amount);
        accountDao.deposit(to, amount);
        // commit transaction
    }
```

Normally this works fine. But let's say that we have two people initiating transfers at the same time. Let's say that Anne wants to transfer 100 bucks to Bob at the same time that Bob wants to transfer 50 to Anne. So in one thread Anne calls `transfer("Anne", "Bob", 100)`, and in another Bob calls `transfer("Bob", "Anne", 50)`. This code is susceptible to dead locks, if the executing order is as follows:

```
T1: accountDao.withDraw("Anne", 100);
T2: accountDao.withDraw("Bob", 50);
T1: accountDao.deposit("Bob", 100);
T2: accountDao.deposit("Anne", 50); // BAM! ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

I admit that I hadn't considered this at all before I started to see dead locks in a real application. My naive view was that the transaction isolation sort of took care of this automatically. Oracle says that this is due to poor application design. But what is a good design in this case? Do I need to `select for update` everything I plan to update? What if this is a huge transaction involving updates several tables? Should I design so that dead locks are impossible or just minimize them and accept that [they are a fact of life?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575497/are-database-deadlocks-a-fact-of-life)

Comment: One tip: Synchronize those transactions that lead to dead-lock, like bank transfers, setting SERIALIZABLE isolation level for those transactions; you can alternatively use synchronized code blocks by using `synchronized(lockObject){}`. These avoids dead-locks in those situations you already know, causing slow throughput, but, it's life!

Comment: In our real system, the deadlock usually happens between a large batch job (long transaction), and user interactions in the GUI. The batch job is scheduled so that only one can run at the same time. But if the batch job would lock the update possibility in the GUI as well, well, that would not be acceptable for the users. Isolation level SERIALIZABLE might be something we should look at. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with SERIALIZABLE in your case is the second transaction trying to update the rows must "wait" for the first one to finish. If the job creates a long transaction, the GUI should wait for it. This is not exactly true as databases implements SERIALIZABLE by executing the transactions in a way it appears to be serialized, but could achieve this in a lot of ways.

Comment: Reconsider the design of the job, as long transactions with GUI interacting with the same rows is problematic to solve. Try to execute shorter transactions in the job, maybe each 1000 rows are updated perform a commit, or the entire job must update the database in a single transaction? Also long transaction impacts database performance as logs (in Oracle, redo and undo logs) need more space to hold the long transaction changes until commit.

Comment: This question reminds me of the old dinning philosophers problem. Well, if your app were the only one accessing the DB, nice things could be done via Java code. Unfortunately this may not be an option for a banking app, since you never know when an external transaction will come in, such as a db procedure or trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a fact of life (and one that should really only happen with high concurrency and hotspot data).

If you wanted to implement lock ordering, then yes, you'd need to rewrite your code to lock or update the accounts in pre-determined order (first Anne, then Bob). But that won't be feasible with complex transactions. If it only happens with a few hotspot rows, maybe you can use lock ordering for just those (and leave the rest as is) and get by with that.

Or use less granular locks, but that will kill your concurrency.

In your case, you can just retry the aborted transaction. And if it happens too often, it does seem like you have some problem with your application design.

Here is [a link for a two-phase commit protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit) for bank account transfers. It is from the MongoDB wiki, i.e. from people who do not even have the luxury of row locks and transactions in the first place, but one could implement that on an RDBMS as well in order to avoid lock contention. That would of course be a rather radical application redesign. I'd try everything else first (retries, coarse locks, artificially reduced concurrency level, batch processing).

Comment: Interesting link. Not really a realistic course of action in my case. It seems that to avoid deadlocks altogether we would have to make huge sacrifices. That's why I asked my question: did we do something completely wrong with our design when we didn't think of this, or is a small number of deadlocks acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

There are few issues with the design above.

Even though you ask about deadlocks, I feel the need to write also about other issues that are wrong IMHO and they might save you from some trouble in the future.

In your design, the first problem I see is the methods separation:
in order to make a modification on the balance, you are having a method to withdraw and a method to deposit. In each, you are using calling the same method "modifyBalance" to do the action. and there are few problems in the way its done:

1- the modifyBalance method requests a connection each time its called
2- the connection will most probably have the auto commit mode on since you did not set auto commit to off.

why is this problematic?
the logic you are doing is supposed to be a single unit. suppose you withdraw 50 from Bob and it succeeds. you have auto commit and the changes are final. now you try to make deposit to Anne and it fails. according to the code above, Anne will not get the 50 but Bob already lost them!!! so in that case you need to call deposit to bob again and return the 50 to him, hoping it won't fail or else ... infinite processing.
therefore, these actions ought to be in the same transaction. either both withdrawing and depositing succeed and they get committed, or they fail and everything is rolled back.

it is also problematic since in auto commit mode, the commit happens after the statement completes or the next execute happens. if for any reason the commit did not happen, then since you are not closing the connection (and that is yet another problem as it does not get back to the pool) and no commit happens might lead to deadlock if another update is issued on the row locked in the first transaction.

therefore, I suggest you do the following: either request the connection in your transfer method , or unite the methods withdraw and deposit in the method modify balance itself.

Since it seems to me that you liked the Idea of having the two methods the way they are, i will demo usage of the first option I mentioned :)

```
public class AccountDao {

    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void withdraw(String account, int amount,Connection connection) throws SQLException{
        modifyBalance(account, -amount);
    }

    public void deposit(String account, int amount,Connection connection) throws SQLException{
        modifyBalance(account, amount);
    }

    private void modifyBalance(String account, int amount,Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("update account set balance = balance + ? where holder = ?");
            statement.setInt(1, amount);
            statement.setString(2, account);
            statement.execute();
   }

}
```

and the transfer method becomes:

```
public void transfer(String from, String to, int amount) {

        try {
            Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            accountDao.withDraw(from, amount,connection);
            accountDao.deposit(to, amount,connection);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            if (connection!=null)
              connection.rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally {
           if (connection!=null){
              connection.commit();
              connection.close();
           }
        }

    }
```

Now either both actions succeed or both get rolled back. Also, when an update is issued on a row, other transactions trying to update the row will wait for it to finish before they can continue. rolling back or committing insures the release of the row level lock.

Now the above is explanation of better design in order to keep the logical actions and the correctness of data. but it won't solve your lock issues !!!! here is an example of what might happen:

suppose thread one is trying to withdraw from bob.

status: row bob locked by t1

at this time, thread two withdraws from anne

status: row anne locked by thread 2

now thread 1 wants to deposit to anne

status: thread 1 sees row anne is locked so it sits and waits for the lock to be    released so it can make the update: thread 1 is actually waiting on thread tweo fo finish the update and commit or roll back the the lock gets released

now thread two wants to deposit to bob

status: bob row is locked so thread two waits for its release

DEADLOCK !!!!!

two threads are waiting on each other.

so how do we solve it ? Please see the answers posted (I saw them while typing this) and please don't accept this answer but accept the one that you actually use to prevent deadlocks. I just wanted to talk about the other issues as I did and sorry for being that long.

Comment: I appreciate that you take the time to write a good answer like this.  But the above code only serves as an example. I am not writing a banking application. It is good that you point out the problem of using two connections, but since I use a transaction manager DataSourceUtils.getConnection() (see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html) returns the connection tied to the transaction. I.e., deposit and withdraw will get the same connection.

Comment: Also if autocommit was on there could be no locking and therefore no deadlock :)

Comment: correct i went to your link and read it. I missed that because I did not use Spring before so i failed to realize that danger is not existing.

Comment: my problem with auto commit was not the deadlock but the fact that if a mistake happens in the last action, you will need to track all the other actions for probable undo.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` on the row before trying to update it. If the row is already locked you will get an error (ORA-00054). Either wait a bit and retry(*) or throw an exception.

You should never run into deadlocks since they are so easily prevented.

---

(*) in this case you would have to retry the whole transaction (after a rollback) to prevent a deadlock situation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this will only allow me to detect the problem, and my only course of action is to roll back one transaction. "Waiting a bit and retry" will never unless I specifically locked BOTH rows at once. Otherwise thread 1 could still lock row A, thread two lock row B, and then I'm stuck in an infinite wait for the other thread to release the lock.

Comment: @waxwing: you're right retrying the failed statement is a bad idea since this would not solve the potential deadlock problem. You would have to retry the whole transaction after a rollback. The solution would be no different than after a deadlock: one transaction has to let go so the other can complete. Still, finding if a row is locked is easy whereas relying on the db to detect the deadlock can be expensive (3-second interval on Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the withdrawl and the deposit are part of a single database transaction, it should be relatively easy to avoid deadlocks simply by working with the accounts in order.  If your application implemented transfers by debiting or crediting the lower account number first then debited or credited the higher account number, you would never be able to deadlock by issuing multiple concurrent transfers.  It doesn't matter from a deadlock prevention standpoint what ordering you enforce (though it may matter for application performance) so long as you are consistent about enforcing that ordering.

Comment: There is also a question about responsibility here. Do you want to put clutter business logic with deadlock prevention code, or is it the responsibility of the DAO? Either way seems like a tradeoff. In a real system, I disagree that preventing deadlocks is simple.

Comment: @waxwing - It may be more difficult in a real system, sure, than in the example we're talking about here.  But there is often a key like `ACCOUNT_NUMBER` that can be used in 99% of the situations to avoid deadlocks.  That does add some complexity to the code, of course, but I would argue that it adds no more complexity than you get from the retry logic that needs to happen if there is a deadlock.  Of course, for some systems, you may accept occasional deadlocks and just train users to retry the operation.  That doesn't work particularly well in banking systems like the example, though.